# Git Repositories updated

Tags: git, github

I would like to keep two Git repositories updated.

First one, is GitHub open source project that gets updated frequently.

Second one is a private held Git Repo located other than GitHub. This one would be modified code for the project requirements.

Occasionally would to update the second repo with first open source project it started from.

There is a custom project build on top of GitHub open source project. Would like to keep it updated and merge from active open source project occasionally.

The GitHub open source project can be cloned.

```
 git clone https://github.com/user/OpenSourceProject.git
```

What would be better way to keep the from the above active repo and keep modifications needed for the custom project.

```
 git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:user/Test.git
```

Comment: Hi @bobsr, welcome to P.SE.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have just updated my question.

Comment: Basically: you have an internal fork and you want to keep the updates. No magic there, this has to be manual. PS: you might want to look at how to have multiple remotes in git.

Comment: git submodule might be what you're looking for, you have one public repository reference your private repository as a submodule.